# Как такое получается что в ASP.NET MVC AnonymousID = null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webbrowser, браузер

Делаю модуль на сайте, который выводит пользователей на сайте за последние 24 часа. Включил  `<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />` на сайте.
При этом у части пользователей `AnonymousID == null`. С чем это может быть связано?

Изучил два случая.
При этом точно знаю что куки у этих клиентов не отключены.

1. Браузер в одном случае был `Chrome` под планшет,
2. Во втором YandexBrowser под мобильный.

Поигрался с браузерными настройками YandexBrowser, обнаружил что при настройке `DoNotTrack` он `AnonymousID` делает нулевым.
И вопрос всё-таки остаётся, почему он попадает в `Null`, ASP.NET MVC как-то обрабатывает настройку `DoNotTrack`? Или это браузер как-то смотрит при такой настройке и подобные куки просто запрещает...
По идее не должно быть таких запретов, так как как я понял 'DoNotTrack' это рекомендация к неотслеживанию, а не меры устраняющие отслеживания.

В первом случае с Chrome `DoNotTrack` вообще выключен, но опять же `AnonymousID == null`.

То есть бывают ситуации когда `AnonymousID == null`, но почему, и возможно ли это исправить и как?

Добавлю, что в большинстве случаях `AnonymousID` проставляется.